# COALESCE in postgresql conditional displaying seemingly undocumented behavior?

Tags: sql, postgresql, coalesce

I have looked at the [COALESCE documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) and it mentions the typical case of using COALESCE to make default/situational parameters, e.g.

```
COALESCE(discount, 5)
```

which evaluates to 5 if discount is not defined as something else.

However, I have seen it used where `COALESCE` actually evaluated all the arguments, despite the documentation explicitly saying it stops evaluating arguments after the first non-null argument.

Here is an example similar to what I encountered, say you have a table like this:

```
id | wind | rain | snow
1  | null |   2  |  3
2  |   5  | null |  6
3  | null |   7  |  2
```

Then you run

```
SELECT *
FROM weather_table
WHERE
    COALESCE(wind, rain, snow) >= 5
```

You would expect this to only select rows with wind `>= 5`, right? NO! It selects all rows with either wind, rain or snow more than 5. Which in this case is 2 rows, specifically these two:

```
2  |   5  | null |  6
3  | null |   7  |  2
```

Honestly, pretty cool functionality, but it really irks me that I couldn't find any example of this online or in the documentation.

Can anyone tell me what's going on? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You would expect this to only select rows with wind >= 5, right?

No, I expect it to select rows with what the Coalesce function returns.

The Coalesce function delivers the value of the *first* non-null parameter. You had `Coalesce(wind,rain,snow)`.  The first row had (null,2,3), so coalesce returned 2. The second row had (5,null,6) so returned 5. The third row had (null,7,2) so returned 7.

The last two rows meet the condition >=5, so 2 rows are retrieved.

Notice that the value for snow was never returned in your example, because either wind or rain always had a value.

Comment: it's hard to describe my confusion now, because the confusion is completely gone after I realized this myself after concocting this minimal reproducible example. That being said, your answer is actually much clearer and better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

After writing out the question so clear, I realized what was going on myself. But I want to answer it here in case anyone else is confused.

Turns out the reason is the `COALESCE` function is run once for each row, which I suppose I could have known. Then it all makes sense.

It checks for each row, do I have non-null wind, if it is `>= 5` I add this row to the result, if not I check if rain is non-null, and so on.

Notably though, if my table was had been like this:

```
id | wind | rain | snow
1  |   0  |   2  |  3
2  |   5  |   0  |  6
3  |   0  |   7  |  2
```

The command would have worked like I thought, and the `COALESCE` function completely useless, would have picked only that one row

```
2  |   5  |   0  |  6
```

equal to `SELECT * FROM weather_table WHERE wind >= 5`.

It only works if there are columns which are null (`0 <> null`).

Comment: I really don't understand your confusion.  Coalesce is a function which returns the first non-null argument (null if none).  Why shouldn't it run against each row like any other function?

Comment: After I typed it out so clear and looking at it again, I don't understand my confusion either. But it was there! In my head I thought my data had 0 I suppose or didn't have it so clearly it was null and worked like this.

Comment: I think it could be helpful for someone else in my position (if there ever is one) to have some examples which work like this, all the examples I found use `select coalesce(wind, 5) etc` which isn't exactly the same as what I described. Difference being using COALESCE to pick which columns you select vs using it to decide which columns to compare to a conditional. (for example, it would not do much in my example to change it to `COALESCE(wind, rain, snow, 5) >= 5`, it would just select all the rows)

Comment: Actually it wouldn't select all the rows, but it would select all rows with only null in them.

Comment: Well - still don't understand your confusion - but I've been there for sure.....

Comment: Haha okay let's describe it like this: In my head I thought the COALESCE function was quite literal in this regard "after finding a non-null argument, the righter ones are not evaluated". I thought it meant the moment it finds a non-null wind, it just stops evaluating rain and snow (also for the other rows). Now again, saying that out loud doesn't make any sense, but in my head that's how it was. There was also no example online using COALESCE to decide columns to compare to a constant to help me understand. But live and learn.

Comment: Ok. Got that one.